# Is it possible to fake a device request to Firebase from a computer?

Tags: android, security, firebase

Let's assume this case:
I use a **Universal Unique IDentifier** to identify my users instead of passwords (I have my reasons). 
I am storing the UUID using `Shared Preferences`, therefore, it is stored in the device.
 I am wondering if some user, different than the legit person using my application, after retrieving the UUID from the phone (after having rooted the phone), can fake a request to Firebase with that UUID and get sensitive information about the legit user.

Thank you for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a single identifier to authenticate users, instead of a combination of email+password (or even better email+password+a second factor) will always be less secure.

Once a malicious actor intercepts the identifier, they can forever perform actions on behalf of that user. Firebase Authentication tokens are not susceptible to such interception, since they're refreshed every hour.

If you don't want to require that your users sign in, consider using [Firebase Authentication's anonymous sign-in](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/anonymous-auth). This will give you the hourly refresh, which your current approach is missing.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I'll take into account this information.